# ruby prawn gem, table position

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, prawn

using prawn gem i display table in the pdf file.. now i want to set position of the table, please guide me how to work on this..

i used the following code to genrate pdf report,

```
pdftable = Prawn::Document.new

pdftable.table([["Name","Login","Email"]],
:column_widths => {0 => 80, 1 => 80, 2 => 80, 3 => 80}, :row_colors => ["d5d5d5"])

 @users.each do|u|
 pdftable.table([["#{u.name}","#{u.login}","#{u.email}"]],
 :column_widths => {0 => 80, 1 => 80, 2 => 80, 3 => 80 }, :row_colors => ["ffffff"])
```

thanks

Comment: how do you want it positioned?

Answer (score 3):

You can use function indent() in combination with functions move_down and move_up,
so for example setting table at position(50,20) (relative to your cursor position) will look like this:

```
move_down 20
indent(50) do #this is x coordinate
    pdftable.table([["Name","Login","Email"]],
    :column_widths => {0 => 80, 1 => 80, 2 => 80, 3 => 80}, :row_colors => ["d5d5d5"])

    @users.each do|u|
    pdftable.table([["#{u.name}","#{u.login}","#{u.email}"]],
    :column_widths => {0 => 80, 1 => 80, 2 => 80, 3 => 80 }, :row_colors => ["ffffff"])
end
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to create a `bounding_box` around the table. See the [documentation for bounding boxes](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/docs/0.11.1/Prawn/Document.html#method-i-bounding_box).

Also: Do you realize you are creating a new table for the header and for each user?

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a dependency to **prawn-layout** (in addition to **prawn**) into your `Gemfile`:

```
# Gemfile
...
gem 'prawn'
gem 'prawn-layout'
...
```

then run a

```
bundle install
```

from the console, to let bundler download the new gem.

After this, you must include, where you want to generate your PDF, in addition to the **prawn** requirement, also the **prawn/layout** requirement:

```
# your_pdf_builder_lib.rb
require 'prawn'
require 'prawn/layout'
```

Done this, the only thing you have to write to center your table is something like this:

```
# your_pdf_builder_lib.rb
require 'prawn'
require 'prawn/layout'
...
def build_pdf
  p = Prawn::Document.new(:page_size => "A4")
  ...
  data = [["header 1", "header 2"], [data_col1, data_col2], ...] # your content for table
  ...
  p.table data, :position => :center # :position => :center will do the trick.
  ...
  p.render
end
```